# Not getting text change value in edit case in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
 <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center">Registration Form</h3>  
                <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="usercontroller">  
                  <input type="hidden" ng-value="id" name="id" ng-model="id" class="form-control" />  
                     <label>First Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" ng-value="name"  name="first_name" ng-model="firstname" class="form-control" />  

                     <br />  
                     <label>Last Name</label>  
                     <input type="text" ng-value="lname" name="last_name" ng-model="lastname" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="btnInsert" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="insertData()" value="ADD"/>  


           <hr>
           <p style="text-align: center;">User List</p>
           <hr> 
           <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr >
                <td>S.no</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;" ng-click=>Action</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
                <td>{{$index +1}}</td>
                <td>{{x.first_name}}</td>
                <td>{{x.last_name}}</td>
              <td><a href="" ng-click="Delete(x.id)">Delete</a></td>
              <td><a href="" ng-click="Edit(x.id)">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
           </table>
           </div> 
            </div> 
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Script Code:

```
<script>  
 var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
 app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope, $http){ 
  $scope.id=0;
  $scope.Edit=function(id){

            $http.post(  
                "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>Registration/Edit",  
                {id :id}  
           ).then(function(response){

           $scope.name = response.data.first_name;
           $scope.lname = response.data.last_name;
           $scope.id = response.data.id;

           });

           } 
  $scope.Delete=function(id){
            $http.post(  
                "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>Registration/Del",  
                {id :id}  
           ).then(function(response){
            name();
            //alert('ok');

           });

           } 
      $scope.insertData = function(){  
         if($scope.id==0){
           $http.post(  
                "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>Registration/add",  
                {'firstname':$scope.firstname, 'lastname':$scope.lastname}  
           ).then(function(response){
            name();

                $scope.firstname = null;  
                $scope.lastname = null;  
           }); 
           } 
           else{
//Here i am not getting the change value from the text box it give me the same value or old value from the text field
            alert($scope.name);

           }
      }
      var name=function(){
        $http.get("<?php echo BASE_URL;?>Registration/view").then(function(response){
                $scope.names = response.data;
            });
           }
           name();

       });  

 </script>
```

This is my front end page for angular crud all listing ,add ,del working fine but the problem is that when i am going to set the value on text field using edit function after how can i get the value after text change its returning me only set value of text after modify this value m not able to get new value please help me related this i am newbe here.

Comment: Is there any solution for this ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You remove ng-value for all the inputs in the HTML

2) in $scope.edit method, append the response data to the models $scope.firstname, $scope.lastname  and $scope.id

These two changes should solve your prob. Angular models supports two way binding.